# Test the current time does it match between two values?

Tags: java, android

I want to test current time. 
Is it the same between the two times?

-With the note, I've already done a job 
function to enter the start time 
and the time to end.

Now i want to complete the special function. 
i'm testing this entry value between the two times.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int hourStart = 5;
        int minuteStart = 30;
        String PMAMStart="AM";
        int hourEnd = 6;
        int minuteEnd = 30;
        String PMAMEnd="AM";

       boolean checkTime=  checkCurrentTimeBetweenTowVlue(hourStart,minuteStart,PMAMStart,hourEnd,minuteEnd,PMAMEnd);

    }


    private boolean checkCurrentTimeBetweenTowVlue(int hStart,int mStart,String ampmStart,int hEnd,int mEnd,String ampmEnd){

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

      return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unless it is a requirement it is probably better for you to use one of the subclasses of `DateTime` such as `LocalDateTime` From memory there are two methods that you can use.

Comment: What's the lowest API level your app is supporting? If it is 26 or higher, then use `java.time` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can set the individual calendar fields such as AM_PM, Hour, and Minute for both start and end dates, convert the time to minutes, and then find the difference between the times. Here is the solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int hourStart = 5;
        int minuteStart = 30;
        String PMAMStart="AM";
        int hourEnd = 6;
        int minuteEnd = 30;
        String PMAMEnd="AM";

        boolean checkTime=  checkCurrentTimeBetweenTwoValues(hourStart,minuteStart,PMAMStart,hourEnd,minuteEnd,PMAMEnd);

        if (checkTime) {
            System.out.println("Time is Same");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Time is not Same");
        }

    }

    private boolean checkCurrentTimeBetweenTwoValues(int hStart,int mStart,String ampmStart,int hEnd,int mEnd,String ampmEnd){

      Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      if (ampmStart.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")) {
          startCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
      } else {
          startCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);
      }

      startCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
      startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hStart);
      startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mStart);

      if (ampmEnd.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")) {
          endCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
      } else {
          endCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);
      }

      endCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
      endCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hEnd);
      endCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mEnd);

      long timeDifference = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
            Math.abs(endCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - startCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
      System.out.println(("Time Difference: " + timeDifference));

      return (timeDifference == 0);
    }
}
```

You can also use `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds` to check for Seconds but for that, you need to set the `Seconds` component of the Calendar instance.

Regards,
AJ

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Java 8 (beginning with API level 26 in Android) or if you are willing / able / allowed to import [a very useful library that enables `java.time` support to lower API levels](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), then the following might be a neat solution:

```
public static boolean isNowBetween(int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour, int endMinute) {
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(startHour, startMinute);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(endHour, endMinute);
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
    return now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get current minutes and hours from cal object. Convert start, end, current time into minutes, then it will be easy to compare.

```
private boolean checkCurrentTimeBetweenTowVlue(int hStart,int mStart,String ampmStart,int hEnd,int mEnd,String ampmEnd){

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 

  if(ampmStart.equals("PM")){
     hStart += 12;
  }
  int minutes_start = hStart*60 + mStart; 

  if(ampmEnd.equals("PM")){
     hEnd += 12;
  }
  int minutes_end = hEnd*60 + mEnd; 

  int minutes_curr = hours*60 + minutes;


  if(minutes_curr>minutes_start && minutes_curr<minutes_end){
     return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Not work  I enter :   int hourStart = 4;
        int minuteStart = 05;
        String PMAMStart="PM";

        int hourEnd = 4;
        int minuteEnd = 30;
        String PMAMEnd="PM";   , the time now equal = 4:03 PM  it 's print : Time is not Same